# Invalid cast exception when passed as object parameter

Tags: c#, casting

Let's say I have two classes where one is convertible into the other:

```
public class Foo { }

public class Bar
{
    public static implicit operator Foo(Bar bar) => new Foo();
}
```

Now I have a method which expects an object as a parameter which it casts to `Foo`.

```
public void DoSomething(object o)
{
    var foo = (Foo)o;
   /* Do something with foo here */
}
```

Now I call this method like so:

```
var bar = new Bar();
var foo = (Foo)bar;

DoSomething(foo);
DoSomething(bar);
```

While the call `DoSomething(foo)` works as expected the call `DoSomething(bar)` throws an `InvalidCastException`. Why can't the runtime use the user-defined type conversion operator in the second method call?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why can't the runtime use the user-defined type conversion operator in the second method call?

Because the compiler isn't executing at execution time... user-defined conversions are noticed by the *compiler*, not the runtime. The cast you've got will basically always fail unless the value is really a `Foo`.

Now the way you can get round this is to use dynamic typing. If you make your method parameter have the `dynamic` type, then the compiler *will* run (to some extent) at execution time, and find your conversion.

Example:

```
using System;

public class Foo { }

public class Bar
{
    public static implicit operator Foo(Bar bar) => new Foo();
}

class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var bar = new Bar();
        var foo = (Foo)bar;

        DoSomething(foo);
        DoSomething(bar);
    }

    static void DoSomething(dynamic o)
    {
        var foo = (Foo) o;
    }
}
```

Of course, it would be better if you could actually change the compile-time type of your parameter to `Foo` instead... is there any reason you can't do that? Note that if you can't change the parameter type at all, you could always convert to `dynamic` in the method:

```
static void DoSomething(object o)
{
    var foo = (Foo) (dynamic) o;
}
```

Comment: I can't change the parameter type because it has to match a delegate.

Comment: @ThomasSchremser: You can create an `Action<object>` with a method group conversion with a method accepting `dynamic` - in the main example in my answer, you could use `Action<object> action = DoSomething;` for example.